# Timeout issues when moving on premises SQL database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I recently moved an on-premise database to the cloud. When we ran our application we received a timeout issue in visual studio. I used importing "data tier application" to move the database from on-premise to the cloud. I did some research and found out that there was no way to increase the timeout duration in cloud (sp_configure function is missing for Azure databases). Just wondering if anyone else experience moving databases from on-premises to the cloud and if you experienced any timeout issues afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout is never a server-side setting.  So increase the [CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?msclkid=8d5a20eecfec11ec9671c381b43e436d&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) in your application, and troubleshoot the slow queries with [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. It's just we never had this issue before until we tried moving an on-premise database to Azure using the import data tier application function.